# robotframework: what is the easiest way to verify a value is bigger than 10

Tags: robotframework

so there is a website: https://www.guruwatch.nl/Aandelen/Default.aspx

I click the element 'koop' and then I want to verify that the value in the top is bigger then 10

id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RightContent_ListAandelen_repAandelen_ctl01_lblCountBuy"

what is the fastest way to do this?

i used

```
Element Text Should Be  ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RightContent_ListAandelen_repAandelen_ctl01_lblCountBuy  24
```

but that is for the exact match, i just want to verify the integer is bigger then 10.

there is also an 
Should Be Equal As Integers    first    second
builtin

but not a 
Should Be Bigger As Integer
Should be Smaller As Integer

p.s. why are those not builtin? is it so strange to use this?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways of checking if one value is larger than another with the `* If` keywords that can be found in the [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Shortcuts) Library. Below is an example of how you can craft the larger than keyword:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Positive
    ${value}    Set Variable    24
    Should Be Larger Than    ${value}    1

Test Negative
    ${value}    Set Variable    24
    Run Keyword And Expect Error    *    Should Be Larger Than  ${value}    100


*** Keywords ***
Should Be Larger Than
    [Arguments]    ${value_1}    ${value_2}
    Run Keyword If    ${value_1} <= ${value_2}    
    ...    Fail    The value ${value_1} is not larger than ${value_2}
```

Comment: The keyword is larger than, which explicitly excludes equal than. So, a conscious choice on my part. As for the casting, you're right, it should happen but given the nature of the question I wanted to provide the simplest version.

Comment: Late night coding, and early starts don't mix. You're right.

Comment: Do consider the casting to numbers - the string "24" **is** larger than the string "105", while when they are numbers - not.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you need to find the xpath locator first. Since the xpath is quite long so, I just assign it to a variable as below.

```
${top_position_xpath}= set variable //span[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RightContent_ListAandelen_repAandelen_ctl01_lblCountBuy'

${get_number}= GET TEXT  xpath=${top_position_xpath} ## --> This is xpath locator for that top column
${check}= SHOULD BE TRUE  ${get_number} > 10 # --> The current test will fail if the result is false..
```

Okay, so I summarize the steps I use above here:

1. Get the xpath locator for the specific column that you want to verify.
2. Use the GET TEXT keyword to get the exact output (number) of that column.
3. Verify using the SHOULD BE TRUE keyword. This keyword is sufficient to verify the condition.

But just to highlight, that if you use the SHOULD BE TRUE keyword as above, the test will fail immediately, so a good approach is to use with keyword RUN AND RETURN STATUS and assign a variable to tell either the condition is true or false, so that you can proceed with your next code or statements..

```
${result}= RUN KEYWORD AND RETURN STATUS    SHOULD BE TRUE    ${get_number} > 10 #
```

Answer (score -1):

Before I read the messages I solved it myself this way:

```
Should Match Regexp  ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RightContent_ListAandelen_repAandelen_ctl01_lblCountBuy  [0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}
```